# Export Sql Data to PDF

Tags: php, mysql

This is my php code : That retrieves a table from Mysql and prints it on the page.

Code:

```
<?php

// Inialize session
session_start();

// Check, if username session is NOT set then this page will jump to login page
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
header('Location: index.php');
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Log in to Intelli-Track</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <link href="1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="css/5grid/init.js?use=mobile,desktop,1000px"></script>
        <script src="js/init.js"></script>
        <noscript>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/5grid/core.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tablestyle.css" />
        </noscript>
        <style type="text/css">

            #main { 
            padding-top:  100px;
            padding-left: 55px; }
            body
{
    line-height: 1.6em;
}

#rounded-corner
{
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 45px;
    width: 480px;
    text-align: left;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#rounded-corner thead th.rounded-company
{
    background: #b9c9fe url('table-images/left.png') left -1px no-repeat;
}
#rounded-corner thead th.rounded-q4
{
    background: #b9c9fe url('table-images/right.png') right -1px no-repeat;
}
#rounded-corner th
{
    padding: 8px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #039;
    background: #b9c9fe;
}
#rounded-corner td
{
    padding: 8px;
    background: #e8edff;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #669;
}
#rounded-corner tfoot td.rounded-foot-left
{
    background: #e8edff url('table-images/botleft.png') left bottom no-repeat;
}
#rounded-corner tfoot td.rounded-foot-right
{
    background: #e8edff url('table-images/botright.png') right bottom no-repeat;
}
#rounded-corner tbody tr:hover td
{
    background: #d0dafd;
}

        </style>



    </head>
    <body>
    <nav id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="landingpage.php">Map-Mark</a></li>
                    <li><a href="logout.php">Log-Out</a></li>
                    <li><a href="credits.html">Credits</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <html>
<body>
<?php
$hostname = '127.0.0.1:3306';        
$dbname   = 'mapmark'; // Your database name.
$username = 'root';             // Your database username.
$password = '';                 // Your database password. If your database has no password, leave it empty.

mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or DIE('Connection to host is failed, perhaps the service is down!');
mysql_select_db($dbname) or DIE('Database name is not available!');
$query="SELECT * FROM markers";
$result=mysql_query($query);

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);
echo "<div id=tab1 style= width:40%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;position:relative;top:200px;>";
echo "<table id=rounded-corner>";//printing table headers
echo '
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="rounded-company">Serial</th>
            <th scope="col" class="rounded-q1">Description</th>
            <th scope="col" class="rounded-q1">Latitude</th>
            <th scope="col" class="rounded-q3">Longitude</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>';
// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))

{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$row[0]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[1]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[2]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[3]</td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table></div>";
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Essentially it looks somewhat like this :

[image: Sql table]

What i need is a button on this page, on clicking which The same table would be downloaded as a PDF file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This might be helpful: "PHP create PDF invoice" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914703/php-create-pdf-invoice

Answer (score 3):

The only viable solution to easily convert html to pdf is by using the domPdf library https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/.

You could add a link to the same page with a `?pdf` get parameter and let your php code output through dompdf when `$_GET['pdf']` is present instead of echo'ing it out to the browser.

See the wiki for usage:
https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/Usage

I think in your case the easiest way would be to add:
`if ( $_GET['pdf'] ) ob_start();`
to the top of your page. (starting an output buffer: see http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

and

```
if ( $_GET['pdf'] ) {
    $html = ob_get_contents(); // this fills $html with all your output generated above.

    //do the dompdf stuff here , using the $html variable.

}
```

to the bottom of your page..