# Content-Type PDF in PHP, not encoded properly

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, content-type

I'm creating a PDF file in PHP:

```
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"file.pdf\"");
echo "Hello";
```

The downloaded `file.pdf` was not able to open. It says "Adobe Reader could not open the file because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded)".

But when opening the file with a **text editor**, only "hello" is there within the file. It looks as if it's not encoded correctly as a PDF. Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just `echo` out a string and expect it to be correctly formatted into a PDF file, "like that".

You need to look into PDF generation. Here are some related questions:

- [PHP PDF Generator Advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350265/php-pdf-generator-advice)
- [PHP create PDF invoice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914703/php-create-pdf-invoice)
- [Generating PDFs with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265760/generating-pdfs-with-php)